# not able to save information to firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I m tring to save course details from the filled form to firebase-database by calling the below function but I m getting some error. Here is a part of my code:

```
Future<void>saveCourseDataToDb(courseName, courseDescription,coursePrice,yearsOfExp, cities) async{
var timeStamp = Timestamp.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;

FirebaseUser teacher= FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser as FirebaseUser;
CollectionReference _courses = Firestore.instance.collection('courses');
try{
  _courses.document(timeStamp.toString()).setData({
    'tutor': {'TeacherName': this.TeacherName, 'Teacherid': teacher.uid },
    'courseName': courseName,
    'courseDescription': courseDescription,
    'coursePrice': coursePrice,
    'yearsOfExp': yearsOfExp,
    'cities': cities,
    'category' : {'categoryName': this.selectedCategory, 'categoryImage': this.categoryImage},
    //'certificate': certificate,
    'published': false,
    'courseId': timeStamp.toString(),
    'courseImage': this.courseURL,
    'certificate' : this.certificateURL
  });
  ErrorAlertDialog(message: 'Course Details saved successfully',);
}catch(e){
  ErrorAlertDialog(message: '${e.toString()}',);
}
return null;
```

}

I get this error:
[image]

And when I declare teacher with Future I get an error related to uid, here is a picture about the same.
[image]

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseUser is a Future, which means you have to "wait" for it to arrive. Try like this

```
FirebaseUser teacher = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Comment: i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

`Future<FirebaseUser>`

use

`Future<User>`

FirebaseUser has been changed to User long time ago & also use **await** before *FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;*

hope this may work ‍♂️.

Comment: It gives this error:: "The name 'User' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument"

Answer (score 0):

try this

first update your firebase plugin to latest version and pub get

then use this

`final FirebaseAuth teacher = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;`

inplace of Future line

hope this time it works